# Marking Checkboxes in Data grid View on the basis of Datatable

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcheckboxcell

I have a Data grid View `dataGridView1` which is bind with a data table `dt1`.

Data table `dt1` has following data:

```
name | status
-----+-------
abc  |   0
abd  |   1
abc  |   0
abc  |   1
abc  |   1
```

I am putting a check box in Data gridview and I want the default value of check box as checked where the status = 1.

```
DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn checkColumn = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();
checkColumn.Name = "X";
checkColumn.HeaderText = "X";

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkColumn);

for (int x = 0; x < countSubCategory; x++)
{
    if (dt1.Rows[x].ItemArray[1].ToString() == "1")
    {
          // here I want to check the checkbox but I don't know what to write here
          checkColumn.Checked= true;
    }

    else { 
        checkColumn.Value = false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: If the datatype is boolean, then the datagrid should display checked or unchecked based on the value once it is bound.

Comment: @MikeSchwartz No it is int data type.

Comment: Is it possible to make a boolean?

Comment: @MikeSchwartz But I am adding the checkbox column separately in the dataGridView. {dataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkColumn);} It is not the part of Datatable. Is it possible to make the checkboxes column part of datatable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead

```
checkColumn.Checked= true;
```

write

```
DataGridName[x][position_of_checkBox_column].Value = true;
```

---

But it is better to work on the data and not on the UI.

you can add to DataTable a Column-expression.

```
dt1.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("X", typeof(bool), "status = 1"));
```

this one line, replaces all the code on the question!

---

Sometimes, more simple and effective, change the SQL statement.

Instead

```
SELECT id, status
```

Write

```
SELECT id, IIF(status = 1, true, false) AS statusBool
```

Comment: its giving me error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool' to 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell'

Comment: Now its giving me this error: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataTable'

Comment: dt1 its a DataTable? how DataGrid linked to data?

Comment: I got the .value = true part, but the assignment fires CellValueChanged with the old value, not the new one. any suggestions?

Comment: @RichardJune `with the old value` What do you mean?

Comment: Brain fart. I was working it incorrectly. Generally fairly clever, but sometimes... I ride the short bus.